# How to install GIT Client in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.10

In ubuntu 12.04 I use the command `sudo apt-get install git` but on a 10.10 machine it won't because its not already available in the repository. Im trying to find a `.deb` but no luck. Can somebody help me find a way to install it?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install git-core`? Btw, maybe this one can help you: http://superuser.com/questions/209471/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-ubuntu-10-10

Comment: @Rob013 Yes. I got E: Unable to locate package git-core

Answer (score 0):

One option is to download and install it from the source code. This way you'll ge the latest upstream version with the latest features:

```
$ wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.3.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz git-1.8.3.1.tar.gz
$ cd git-1.8.3.1
$ make
$ make install
```

This will install the git binaries on your ~/bin/ directory. For other installation options, see the INSTALL file on the source directory root.